# 40Mhz pulse counting and storing count value

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, performance

I am new to Raspberry pi.

I need to count 40 Mhz continuous pulse for every 100 microseconds and store the count in micro SD card before next cycle starts. The process should run for 24 hours.

I am planning to use Raspberry pi since it's base frequency is 700 Mhz. It is possible to do?

If not, please suggest any other solution to do the same.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your previous question.  What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: I am still in confusion which device to use. Please suggest the best to do.

Comment: Sorry. I want to mention my actual requirement , so i posted as new question